# Which eslint rules in my config are slow?

Tags: javascript, profiling, configuration-files, eslint

I have a config with around 100 rules, and running eslint on my project with all these rules takes around 10 seconds. I'd like to identify the slowest rules and eliminate some of them. How do I do this? Is there any profiler tool for eslint?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

eslint shows the spent times of rules if the environment variable `TIMING` is set.
For example:

```
$ TIMING=1 eslint lib
Rule                         | Time (ms) | Relative
:----------------------------|----------:|--------:
valid-jsdoc                  |   203.798 |     6.7%
camelcase                    |   142.146 |     4.6%
no-unmodified-loop-condition |   136.811 |     4.5%
indent                       |   127.138 |     4.2%
no-undefined                 |   124.525 |     4.1%
keyword-spacing              |    85.397 |     2.8%
space-in-parens              |    76.179 |     2.5%
no-this-before-super         |    72.317 |     2.4%
no-implied-eval              |    69.945 |     2.3%
space-infix-ops              |    57.128 |     1.9%
```

See also the official docs on [Per-rule Performance](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules#per-rule-performance).

Comment: Too bad it doesn't show the parser timer. I'm using `@typescript-eslint/parser` and it's taking a long time, wanted a benchmark on it.

Comment: Indeed, I have the same issue with the `@typescript-eslint/parser`, with a file of 400 lines it takes about 6 seconds, the actual rules are comparatively fast, 600ms being the slowest and also (99.6% of the relative). So at least 5.4 seconds disappearing to parsing. An unfortunate thing with the `--cache` is that it doesn't work with `--stdin` something which tripped me up in trying to optimize this as an editor integration.

Answer (score 40):

I found that removing slow rules didn't really help that much, as loading `eslint` and parsing files takes a while.

It is possible to use the `--cache` option of `eslint` ([docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#caching)) to speed things up substantially.

When using `eslint` to "lint-as-you-type" in various editors, installing [eslint_d](https://github.com/mantoni/eslint_d.js) allows running `eslint` as a daemon, and saves the `node` loading time.

On the project I'm currently working on, combining both `eslint_d` and `--cache` brought the linting time from 4+ seconds to 0.17!

Comment: I use vim with the [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) plugin for linting. Setting `let g:ale_javascript_eslint_executable = 'eslint_d --cache'` to use both `eslint_d` and `--cache` speed it up from ~1 second to be almost instant!

Comment: I use eslint via the Syntastic plugin for VIM. Any info about how to enable `--cache` while running from Syntastic?

Comment: I don't use syntastic myself, but the [docs](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqcheckers) under section 4.5 mention how to pass options to a checker, I'm guessing in your case something like `let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_args = "--cache"`

Comment: There's a few options I had to change to get `eslint_d` working correctly with syntastic.

`let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_exe = 'eslint_d'
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_args = "--cache"
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_exec = '/bin/ls'`

Lastly, you need to ensure `eslint_d` is in the PATH when vim is launched.

Comment: How can we use this with `create-react-app` ?

Comment: This is the solution to this problem, and I'm pretty sad that pretty much no other threads anywhere mention `eslint_d`.

Comment: From the documentation: "Atom, VSCode: You will not gain any performance from this module as these editors already cache eslint instances for you."

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` (linting with type information) and I'd misconfigured the tsconfig `include` field. Based on [this doc](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/TYPED_LINTING.md) you have to include all your files. So I updated my eslint configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts'],
      parserOptions: {
-       project: ['tsconfig.json'],
-       createDefaultProgram: true,
+       project: ['tsconfig.json', './projects/*/tsconfig.json'],
+       createDefaultProgram: false,
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

This can also happen if you're using `@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin`. Read [the performance section of their docs](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#eslint-configs-and-performance)

Comment: I think the relevant `@typescript-eslint` doc is now here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/docs/linting/MONOREPO.md

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well, this was because I enabled `createDefaultProgram: true`, removing it increased my performances significantly !!